# regular expression start (^) does not work correctly

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a pattern like `091\d{8}` in a content.
I want to extract strings that start with `091`, I try this:

```
^(091)\d{8}
```

this pattern only match when string begins in new line,what pattern must I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` will only match the number if the string starts with 091, not in between.
You should match word boundaries in your regular expression ,
else it will fetch those expressions too which start with 091, but have more than 8 digits after that.

See this regex  `\b((091)\d{8})\b` working at : http://regexr.com?310ra

The caputred group in parenthesis will give you the required number.

Comment: You don't need all those capturing groups. You can just remove all brackets, the result is then the whole match.

Answer (score 3):

You should match for a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (\b)

Comment: The parentheses should also include the `\d{8}` to include whole word in the capture group.  Something like `\b(091\d{8})`.

Comment: @phatfingers, the brackets are not needed at all. Why do you need a capturing group, when the group is the whole pattern?